# Error when deploying File Connector in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

below is the error I receive after deploying my car file onto wso2 EI 6.6.0 / 7.0.0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZyI1.png)

I created the file transfer method on integration studio 8.0.1 and I added a file connector mediator version 4.0.11.

After I deploy the car file on EI I get a

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.library.service.MediationLibraryAdminService} - Unable to update status for : {org.wso2.carbon.connector}file :: Template configuration : null cannot be built for Synapse Library artifact
```

Followed by a error displaying :

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator} - Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.file.init cannot be found
```

First, the synapse-libs folder was empty so I added the file connector zipped file into it and then the {org.wso2.carbon.connector}file was created in the imports folder. But even after doing this, I still get that error back.

I have tried connecting locally as well as ftp to local.

I used a YouTube video to implement this transfer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2q7Y176Euw

These are my Sequences :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0CQm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WciM.png)

My Scheduled task:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Jdl.png)

My Local entries:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRzFS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUAIE.png)

Any Assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the full stack traces? Also did you create a Connector Exporter project and added the Capp?

Comment: Also, in the latest File Connector, there is no `init` operation. You can refer https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/file-connector/file-connector-example/

Comment: Yes I added the file connector in the connector exporter and then exported the Car file to EI.

Comment: So regarding the Init operation, before I enable the file connector on wso2 EI, I was receiving same error but with ListFiles ( which is using in my FileListenerseq)  and after it is enabled, I receive the Init operation error

Comment: You don't need to manually add the connector zip to the `synapse-libs` when deploying a car. It seems like the connector is not packed in the car.

Comment: So when I deploy the Car file onto EI, the file connector is deployed under connectors as well. However, in the Syanpse-libs folder, its empty

Comment: Are you using an EI 6.6.0 base pack? The file connector v4.x.x needs an updated pack due to compatibility issues.

Comment: I have tried to deploy the CarApp on EI 7.0.0  as well and the same error persists.

Comment: You need an updated  EI 7.0.0 as well. MI 1.2.0(EI 7.1.0) and above base packs have the file connector v4.x.x support without any updates. Older EI versions need to be updated to the latest versions in order to use file connector v4.x.x.